# Can you find the error in my function call?

Tags: python

```
que = queue.Queue()
get_videos(que)


def get_videos(self, theQue):
        links = input('Enter links comma seperated: ')
        list = links.split(',')
        for i in list:
                theQue.put(i)
        return
```

My current code says "NameError get_videos is not defined"
I guess I tried with and without self and neither help maybe I'm confused how this works.

Comment: self is only used in classes. Since this is not in a class, self is just another variable to pass to your function. You definitely should remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function before its definition, the interpreter has no clue what `get_videos` you are talking about or trying to call here, so you need to call it after it's defined

```
que = queue.Queue()


def get_videos(theQue):
        links = input('Enter links comma seperated: ')
        list = links.split(',')
        for i in list:
                theQue.put(i)
        return
get_videos(que)
```

Also `self` param is only for class methods, you could name your parameters anything you want, but you are passing only one value, the `self` gets passed automatically when you call this function on a class instance -it should be defined within the class-

Comment: I was hoping to link in a good explanation of _why_ python is like this; [here's the best I found on short notice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3756598/10135377).

Answer (score 0):

You should write like that:

```
   def get_videos(self, theQue):
    links = input('Enter links comma seperated: ')
    list = links.split(',')
    for i in list:
            theQue.put(i)
    return
   que = queue.Queue()
   get_videos(que)
```

Comment: With this function not in a class, it should NOT have self. Even if it is in a class, it should be a staticmethod since it doesn't use self.