# Python NameError: name 'print_x' is not defined

Tags: python, function

I am new to python and have a very simple question:

```py
x="hello World"
print_x()

def print_x():
    print(x)
```

this outputs `NameError: name 'print_x' is not defined`
and I don't know why because i defined it right there.

(This is my first time writing a function)

Comment: It needs to be defined _before_ you try and access it.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754240/declare-function-at-end-of-file-in-python

Comment: @Dennis ok thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you wrote your function AFTER you called it. Python is a scripting language, so you need to have the function declared before you call it.